# long lengths of adjustable shelves

Tags: word-usage

What is the singular of this phrase?

> long lengths of adjustable shelves

Is the singular number of *long lengths of adjustable shelves* this?

> an adjustable shelf with long lengths

Please correct it.

Comment: A long length of adjustable shelving.

Answer (score 1):

A *length* can be used as a countable measure (albeit not clearly defined), as shown by [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/length):

> 3 [COUNTABLE] a piece of something that is long and thin
>   *a length of pipe/rope/string*

But in that case we usually do not add an adjective to it like *long*. It can be used in a way similar to *meter*:

> I bought *three lengths* of the finest silk.

Obviously, in the singular that would be:

> I bought a length of the finest silk.

Adding *long* to it *can* be done to emphasize the extent of the lengths, as we can do with kilometers:

> He bought 100 long lengths of cloth.
>   He walked 10 long kilometers home.

The actual size of a lengths or a kilometer is not longer than usual, but is may appear longer.

When using *long* with a *singular* length, I can only assume that is *is* longer than one would expect (which is easy, since I do not think a *length* is  a very well-defined measure of size).

So the singular of your sentence would be:

> a long length of adjustable shelf.

Note that I also changed *shelves* to *shelf*, although that doesn't make it really singular. I would actually have used *shelf* in your original sentence, using it as a mass-noun, or alternatively, *shelving*, as Andrew Leach noted.

Comment: The singular of *shelves* is *shelf*. A suitable mass noun might be *shelving*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Aargh, of course. Thanks for pointing out that orthographic blunder.